# Proof by contradiction to show uniform convergence (how to formulate the condition)

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-writing, uniform-convergence

Suppose we have functions $f_n$ with $f_n(x) \to g$ as $x \to 0$. I need to show that this convergence is uniformly in $n$ and I want to do it by proof by contradiction. But I have problems with the contradiction assumption.

As in, "Suppose the convergence is not uniform. Then ..." what to put here? There is something like: "Then for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a subsequence $n_j$ such that $|f_n(x)-g| \geq \epsilon$..." But I don't know.

Comment: The hypothesis "$f_n(x)\to f_n(0)$ as $x\to 0$ says simply that all the $f_n$ are continuous in $0$. You can not get much uniform convergence of this.

Comment: Again, the hypothesis is extremely weak. The only difference is that now $\lim_{x\to 0}f_n(x)$ is independent of $n$. The counterexample of my answer applies again. And your function $g$ is a constant.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but I believe you misunderstood the question. I am not asking for a proof that the convergence is uniform for some arbitrary sequence. I am just asking how I would go about constructing a proof by contradiction for my particular sequence. I just don't know what the correct start should be for the proof by contradiction.

Comment: The statement you're trying to proof is not true to start with. Maybe this is because you've written it incorrectly or that you missed to include some important premises. Take for example $f_n(x) = g+nx$, it's true that $f_n(x)\to g$ as $x\to 0$, but still $f_n$ does not converge in $n$ and certainly not uniformly.

Comment: Agree with all the above comments. I think you need additional conditions for the convergence to be uniform. For example, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini's_theorem)

Comment: Also, one example that probably is useful is as follows (Le Cam, Asymptotic Methods in Statistical Decision Methods, p644). Let $f_v$ be a net on $C(E, F)$, then it converges to $f_0 \in C(E, F)$ for compact convergence iff. $x_{\alpha} \rightarrow x_0$ implies $\lim_{v, \alpha}f_v(x_{\alpha}) = f_0(x_0)$

Comment: We have read the OP and it is fairly clear the way you formulated your question is confusing, especially with respect to notations, which, as the answer has pointed out makes no sense to ask to begin with. Therefore, we have to assume that you meant to ask something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saying "$f_n(x)\to f_n(0)$ uniformly" doesn't makes many sense because the "limit" depends of $n$.

Even reinterpreting as "$f_n(x) - f_n(0)\to 0$ uniformly", is false: take $f_n(x) = n|x|$.

EDIT:

The uniform convergence means
$$\forall\epsilon>0\ \exists\delta_\epsilon>0\ \forall x\in(-\delta_\epsilon,\delta_\epsilon)\ \forall n\in\Bbb N:\ |f_n(x) - g|<\epsilon.$$
The negation of this is:
$$\exists\epsilon>0\ \forall \delta>0\ \exists x_\delta\in(-\delta,\delta)\ \exists n_\delta\in\Bbb N :\ |f_{n_\delta}(x_\delta) - g|\ge\epsilon.$$

And remember again: $g$ is a constant.  The difference *isn't* $|\cdots - g(x)|$.

Comment: So sorry, I made a mistake. Please see the edit.

Comment: Aren't you saying here that $f_n(x) \to g$ as $n \to \infty$ (uniformly in $x$)? This isn't what the OP has. His uniformity is wrt. $n$ as $x \to 0$.

Comment: @25Chars, edited.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain what you mean by "The difference isn't ..."??? Just that $g(x) \equiv g$?>

Comment: @PostName, right.